# Programmatically (PHP) save image with no extension

Tags: php

I am trying to save to disk an image that is served to me via a JSON result. The returned JSON result property that I am interested in is this:

```
https://i.scdn.co/image/6cd03f58ddf30a1393f06d6469973ba16ac908df
```

Which is the correct image. The problem is that, while the above URL does display the image, it does not allow me to download it, yet I can download it by right-clicking on it.

What I need to be able to do is, using my PHP code, save it to disk.

I have no issues saving results from other sites that give results that link to a direct image extension (.jpg, .gif or .png). But I have not been able to figure out how to programmatically download the image from the above URL.

Is it possible?

This is the code that I use, which works correctly on results that give a URL that has a correct image extension. The URL returned is loaded into the $largeimg variable.

```
$input = $largeimg;
$output = 'image.jpg';
file_put_contents($output, file_get_contents($input));
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: put your php code into `image.php` and treat that file as if it's a jpg (or whatever) file. Then simply output to screen using `imagejpeg($imageData, NULL,70);` from within that PHP.

Comment: The pattern of your URL has no influence whatsoever on whether you can access the object behind it or not. "File name extensions" actually are a means from the past that has no real technical sense any more. If you fail to download the image from php then this has nothing to do with such an "extension", but either with a fault in your code or with the fact that the request you send programmatically differs from a request sent by a browser, for example by a missing http header or similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` is able to accept raw URI arguments. Your code works perfectly for me, if modified in the way:

```
$input = 'https://i.scdn.co/image/6cd03f58ddf30a1393f06d6469973ba16ac908df';
```

So, `file_get_contents()` can download the image directly. I think, the problem is your `$largeimg` variable.

Comment: Hi @abcdn thanks. You are right, it does work like that and you are also right, it was an issue with the variable $largeimg, it had whitespace in it which must have been breaking it. I have used trim() and it now works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I know, whitespase is an evil thing. Glad to be helpful, anyway!